# DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text Getting always the same Value

Tags: data-binding, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I am following the next explanation: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c19e8/dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-in-gridview-and-saving/

And actually, after clicking the value in the dropdown, then, when it makes postback, it is always displaying the same item (the first one).

I have been reading about possible solutions, I also checked if I am databinding in Page Load, then wrapping the binding code as:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{

    // Your binding code here ...

}
```

But actually I wrapp every databinding (I just follow that URL I commented above). Thus, I am kinda getting crazy with that.

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewTitulaciones" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="Gridview1_RowCreated"
            >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="datafieldTitulacion" HeaderText="Nº Titulación" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Titulación">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownTitulacion" runat="server" Width="250px"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Universidad">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownUniversidad" runat="server"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="250px"></asp:DropDownList>                    
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fecha fin de estudios">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDateFechaFinEstudios" runat="server" CssClass="CampoNormal" Width="250px"
                         ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd_newRowTitulacionUniversidad" runat="server"   
                                     Text="Add New Row"   
                                     onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" /> 
                      <!--  <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"
                            Text="Add New Row"
                             /> -->
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                             onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and here is my .aspx:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)

            SetInitialRow();

        }
    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    } 


private void FillDropDownList_titulacion(DropDownList ddl)
{


        ddl.DataSource = BC.Titulacion.Listar();
        ddl.DataTextField = "DESC_TITULACION";
        ddl.DataValueField = "TITULACION_ID";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "-1"));
        ddl.Items[0].Selected = true;


}

private void FillDropDownList_universidad(DropDownList ddl)
{


        ddl.DataSource = BC.CentroFormativo.Listar();
        ddl.DataTextField = "DESC_CENTRO";
        ddl.DataValueField = "CENTRO_TIPO_ID";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "-1"));
        ddl.Items[0].Selected = true;

}  

private void SetInitialRow()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("datafieldTitulacion", typeof(string)));
    //dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
    //dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnTitulaciones", typeof(string)));//for DropDownList selected item   
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnUniversidades", typeof(string)));//for DropDownList selected item   

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["datafieldTitulacion"] = 1;
    dr["ColumnTitulaciones"] = string.Empty;
    dr["ColumnUniversidades"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //Store the DataTable in ViewState for future reference   
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    //Bind the Gridview   
    gridviewTitulaciones.DataSource = dt;
    gridviewTitulaciones.DataBind();

    //After binding the gridview, we can then extract and fill the DropDownList with Data   
    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)gridviewTitulaciones.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("dropdownTitulacion");
    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)gridviewTitulaciones.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("dropdownUniversidad");
    FillDropDownList_titulacion(ddl1);
    FillDropDownList_universidad(ddl2);
}

private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["datafieldTitulacion"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;

            //add new row to DataTable   
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            //Store the current data to ViewState for future reference   

            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;


            //String p = dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                //extract the DropDownList Selected Items   

                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)gridviewTitulaciones.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("dropdownTitulacion");
                DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)gridviewTitulaciones.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("dropdownUniversidad");

                //String s =  ddl1.Items[5].Text;
                // Update the DataRow with the DDL Selected Items   
                // int igh = ddl1.SelectedIndex;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["ColumnTitulaciones"] = ddl1.SelectedItem.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["ColumnUniversidades"] = ddl2.SelectedItem.Text;

            }

            //Rebind the Grid with the current data to reflect changes   


                gridviewTitulaciones.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                gridviewTitulaciones.DataBind();



        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");

    }
    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks   
    SetPreviousData();
}

private void SetPreviousData()
{

    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {



                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)gridviewTitulaciones.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("dropdownTitulacion");
                DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)gridviewTitulaciones.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("dropdownUniversidad");

                //Fill the DropDownList with Data   
                FillDropDownList_titulacion(ddl1);
                FillDropDownList_universidad(ddl2);

                if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {

                    //Set the Previous Selected Items on Each DropDownList  on Postbacks   
                    ddl1.ClearSelection();
                    ddl1.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["ColumnTitulaciones"].ToString()).Selected = true;

                    ddl2.ClearSelection();
                    ddl2.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["ColumnUniversidades"].ToString()).Selected = true;

                }

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}  

protected void Gridview1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
        if (lb != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowIndex == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    lb.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lb.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
    int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                //Remove the Selected Row data and reset row number  
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);
                ResetRowID(dt);
            }
        }

        //Store the current data in ViewState for future reference  
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        //Re bind the GridView for the updated data  
        gridviewTitulaciones.DataSource = dt;
        gridviewTitulaciones.DataBind();
    }

    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks  
    SetPreviousData();
}

private void ResetRowID(DataTable dt)
{
    int rowNumber = 1;
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row[0] = rowNumber;
            rowNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured some way out. The point is that the dropdownlist got several equal values (items), so I just rebuild my list of items making them uniques. Then, It works.